# How to invoke class method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Common;

public class General_function
{
    internal System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView DG_ItemShow;

    public static object Get_Single_Value(string SQLQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            object SingleValue = null;
            DbConnection cn = database_Object.GetConnection(database_Object.Provider);
            DbCommand cmd = database_Object.GetCommand(database_Object.Provider);

            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.Trasns_DataConnectionString;
                cn.Open();
            }

            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = SQLQuery;     
            SingleValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar;

            return SingleValue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("error in Get_Single_Value :  " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static long get_Max_value(string tablename, string fieldname)
    {
        try
        {
            long maxvalue = 0;
            DbConnection cn = database_Object.GetConnection(database_Object.Provider);
            DbCommand cmd = database_Object.GetCommand(database_Object.Provider);

            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.Trasns_DataConnectionString;
                cn.Open();
            }

            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select max(" + fieldname + ") From " + tablename;
            string res = null;
            res = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
            {
                maxvalue = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                maxvalue = long.Parse(res);
            }
            return maxvalue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("Error in get_Max_value" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static int Save_Record(ArrayList Al, string TableName)
    {
        try
        {
            int Retval = 0;
            Trasns_DataDataSet ds = new Trasns_DataDataSet();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables(TableName);
            ArrayList tal = new ArrayList();

            foreach (DataColumn cl in dt.Columns)
            {
                tal.Add(cl.ColumnName);
            }

            DbConnection cnn = default(DbConnection);
            cnn = database_Object.GetConnection(database_Object.Provider);
            cnn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.Trasns_DataConnectionString;
            cnn.Open();
            DbCommand cmd1 = default(DbCommand);
            cmd1 = database_Object.GetCommand(database_Object.Provider);
            cmd1.Connection = cnn;
            string n = null;

            for (int i = 0; i <= tal.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                n = "@" + tal(i).ToString;
                DbParameter pa = database_Object.GetParameter(database_Object.Provider);
                pa.ParameterName = n;
                pa.Value = Al(i);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(pa);
            }

            n = "";
            string v = "";
            string sqlstr = "insert into " + TableName + " (";

            for (int i = 0; i <= tal.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                n = n + "," + tal(i).ToString;
                v = v + ",@" + tal(i).ToString;
            }

            n = Strings.Right(n, Strings.Len(n) - 1);
            v = Strings.Right(v, Strings.Len(v) - 1);
            sqlstr = sqlstr + n + ") values (" + v + ")";
            cmd1.CommandText = sqlstr;
            Retval = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery;
            return Retval;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("error in  Save_Record :  " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static int Delete_Record(ArrayList AlName, ArrayList AlValue, string TableName)
    {
        try
        {
            int Retval = 0;
            DbConnection cnn = default(DbConnection);
            cnn = database_Object.GetConnection(database_Object.Provider);
            cnn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.Trasns_DataConnectionString;
            cnn.Open();
            DbCommand cmd1 = default(DbCommand);
            cmd1 = database_Object.GetCommand(database_Object.Provider);
            cmd1.Connection = cnn;
            string m = null;

            for (int i = 0; i <= AlName.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                m = "@" + AlName(i).ToString;
                DbParameter pa = database_Object.GetParameter(database_Object.Provider);
                pa.ParameterName = m;
                pa.Value = AlValue(i);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(pa);
            }

            string sqlstr = "delete from " + TableName + " where ";
            string v = "";

            for (int i = 0; i <= AlName.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                v = v + " And " + AlName(i).ToString + "=@" + AlName(i).ToString;
            }

            v = Strings.Right(v, Strings.Len(v) - 4);
            sqlstr = sqlstr + v;
            cmd1.CommandText = sqlstr;
            Retval = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery;
            return Retval;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("error in Delete_Record :  " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static int Modify_Record(ArrayList AlName, ArrayList AlValue, ArrayList    
    AlPKName, ArrayList AlPKValue, string TableName)
    {
        try
        {
            int Retval = 0;
            DbConnection cnn = default(DbConnection);
            cnn = database_Object.GetConnection(database_Object.Provider);
            cnn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.Trasns_DataConnectionString;
            cnn.Open();
            DbCommand cmd1 = default(DbCommand);
            cmd1 = database_Object.GetCommand(database_Object.Provider);
            cmd1.Connection = cnn;
            string m = null;
            //values parameters

            for (int i = 0; i <= AlName.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                m = "@" + AlName(i).ToString;
                DbParameter pa = database_Object.GetParameter(database_Object.Provider);
                pa.ParameterName = m;
                pa.Value = AlValue(i);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(pa);
            }

            //primary key column parameters
            for (int i = 0; i <= AlPKName.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                m = "@" + AlPKName(i).ToString;
                DbParameter pa = database_Object.GetParameter(database_Object.Provider);
                pa.ParameterName = m;
                pa.Value = AlPKValue(i);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(pa);
            }

            string sqlstr = "update " + TableName + " set ";
            string v = "";

            for (int i = 0; i <= AlName.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                v = v + "," + AlName(i).ToString + "=@" + AlName(i).ToString;
            }

            string w = "";

            for (int i = 0; i <= AlPKName.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                w = w + " And " + AlPKName(i).ToString + "=@" + AlPKName(i).ToString;
            }

            v = Strings.Right(v, Strings.Len(v) - 1);
            w = Strings.Right(w, Strings.Len(w) - 4);
            sqlstr = sqlstr + v + " Where " + w;
            cmd1.CommandText = sqlstr;
            Retval = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery;
            return Retval;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("error in Modify_Record :  " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static DataTable RecordSearch(string SqlString, string TableName)
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnection cnn = default(DbConnection);
            cnn = database_Object.GetConnection(database_Object.Provider);
            cnn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.Trasns_DataConnectionString;
            cnn.Open();
            Trasns_DataDataSet ds = new Trasns_DataDataSet();
            DataTable dt = default(DataTable);
            DbDataAdapter da = database_Object.GetAdapter(database_Object.Provider);
            DbCommand cmd = database_Object.GetCommand(database_Object.Provider);
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandText = SqlString;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds, TableName);
            dt = ds.Tables(TableName);

            cnn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
            cnn.Dispose();
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("error in RecordSearch :  " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call the this class method from another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as shown in code, you defined method as `static` so in order to invoke that method u can use,

`var o = General_function.Get_Single_Value("your_parameter");`

and

`long lobj = General_function.get_Max_value("table_name","field_name");`

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Using your static methods, you just call them by referencing the namespace:

```
object result = General_function.Get_Single_Value("select * from table");
```